# Programmatically launch the Mac's System Preferences screen -> Sound

Tags: macos, cocoa, operating-system

Is there a programmatic way to launch the system settings on Mac and have it focus on the sound pane?

If so, is there a programmatic way to have it default on the "Output" tab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can applescript it:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
    reveal anchor "Output" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
```

Adapted from [this link](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html).

Answer (score 16):

There is an easier way:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Speech.prefPane"];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular problem: 
I wanted to open the "privacy" tab in the "security & privacy" system preferences pane.

You can achieve this from a terminal using this command:

```
open x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy
```

Therefore I tried the following in my app which did not work:

```
// does not work!!!
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy"]];
```

So I implemented this kind of hacky solution:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.launchPath = @"/bin/sh";
task.arguments = @[@"-c" , @"open x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy"];
[task launch];
```

Tested on macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: Try to create NSURL not with path  (fileURLWithPath) but with String: [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];